# Manipulating Azure storage containers in a Django project

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In a Django project, I'm uploading video files to an Azure storage via the following snippet:

```
content_str = content.read()
blob_service.put_blob(
            'videos',
            name,
            content_str,
            x_ms_blob_type='BlockBlob',
            x_ms_blob_content_type=content_type,
            x_ms_blob_cache_control ='public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=86400'
        )
```

where `name` is a random `uuid` string and `videos` is the name of the container. How do I upload the video files without specifying a container, i.e. de facto creating a unique container for every file I upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I upload the video files without specifying a container, i.e.
>   de facto creating a unique container for every file I upload?

Each blob (a video file in your case) must belong to a container. So what you could do is create a container using `blob_service.create_container` before you call `blob_service.put_blob`. You can name the container as `uuid`.